# Recursive common table expression 'temp_table4' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a query which will reference multiple CTEs. To check the code was working, I created the query and on conclusion of the result, I migrated it to a cte and completed the inner joins.

When I checked the query in `temp_table3`, the data returned was correct, but when I added this as a CTE and ran the next query, I noted that the results started to multiply, which is incorrect, as i should only ever have 3 records. I commented this out in the end of the main query :(

I then added a new cte called temp_table4 which correctly returned the summed data, however when i add this to the final query, I get an error:

> Recursive common table expression 'temp_table4' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator

I need to add another 7 ctes to finish the full query, but to be honest, I am now officially stuck.

Can somebody help me understand what/where I have gone wrong with the multiplying records and help resolve the union all error?

I thought I would add the table, the raw data and the query I have been working on.

Table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK]
(
    [pbatch_code] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [outflow_rate] [int] NULL,
    [qty] [int] NULL,
    [start_inflow] [datetime] NULL,
    [end_outflow] [datetime] NULL,
    [duration] [float] NULL,
    [custom_string_1] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [custom_string_2] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [model_name] [nvarchar](80) NULL
)
```

The raw data contents is:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK ([pbatch_code], 
              [outflow_rate], [qty], [start_inflow],
              [end_outflow], [duration], [custom_string_1], 
              [custom_string_2], [model_name])
VALUES
 ('P31200','1200','44342','2021-05-25 03:10:00','2021-05-26 
 14:23:00','2113','used by macro','15000351','ISK_AS_VI'),
 ('P31202','1200','42279','2021-05-25 02:23:00','2021-05-26 
 13:36:00','2113','used by macro',   
 '15000351','ISK_AS_VI'),
 ('P31204','1200','42280','2021-05-25 07:46:00','2021-05-26 
 19:01:00','2114','used by macro','15000351','ISK_AS_VI'); `
```

My full query is:

```
WITH temp_table1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        MAX(start_inflow) AS Latest_start_time,
        custom_string_2 AS item_code,
        COUNT(custom_string_2) AS number_batches,
        SUM(duration) / 60 AS Delta_duration_sum 
    FROM 
        dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb1 
    WHERE 
        (custom_string_1 = 'used by macro') 
    GROUP BY 
        custom_string_2
) 
---- Latest_start_time, DeltahoursLatestStart_time, 
Delta_duration_Sum
, temp_table2
AS
(
SELECT pb2.custom_string_2 AS item_code,
DATEDIFF 
(minute,pb2.start_inflow,tt1.Latest_start_time)/60.0 AS 
[DeltaHoursLatestStart_time]
FROM temp_table1 AS tt1
INNER JOIN dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb2
ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt1.item_code
WHERE (custom_string_1 = 'used by macro') 
)
----tt3.[Duration to delta]
,temp_table3 
AS
(
select 
pb2.custom_string_2 AS item_code,
sum(tt2.DeltaHoursLatestStart_time) AS Duration_to_delta
,pb2.pbatch_code
FROM temp_table1 AS tt1
INNER JOIN dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb2
ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt1.item_code
INNER JOIN temp_table2 AS tt2
ON tt1.item_code = tt2.item_code
WHERE (custom_string_1 = 'used by macro') 
GROUP BY Pb2.custom_string_2,pb2.pbatch_code
)
,temp_table4 
AS
(
select 
pb2.custom_string_2 AS item_code,
sum(tt2.DeltaHoursLatestStart_time+tt3.Duration_to_delta) 
as Test
,pb2.pbatch_code
FROM temp_table1 AS tt1
INNER JOIN dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb2
ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt1.item_code
INNER JOIN temp_table2 AS tt2
ON tt1.item_code = tt2.item_code
INNER JOIN temp_table3 AS tt3
ON tt2.item_code = tt3.item_code
INNER JOIN temp_table4 AS tt4
ON tt2.item_code = tt4.item_code
WHERE (custom_string_1 = 'used by macro') 
GROUP BY Pb2.custom_string_2,pb2.pbatch_code
)
select distinct
pb2.start_inflow
,tt1.latest_start_time
,tt1.item_code
,tt1.number_batches
,tt1.Delta_duration_sum
,pb2.end_outflow
,pb2.duration
,pb2.pbatch_code
,pb2.outflow_rate
,pb2.qty
--,tt2.DeltaHoursLatestStart_time
,tt3.Duration_to_delta
,tt4.Test
FROM temp_table1 AS tt1
INNER JOIN dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb2
ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt1.item_code
INNER JOIN temp_table2 AS tt2
ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt2.item_code
INNER JOIN temp_table3 AS tt3
ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt3.item_code AND PB2.pbatch_code= tt3.pbatch_code
INNER JOIN temp_table4 AS tt4
ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt4.item_code
WHERE(pb2.custom_string_2 IS NOT NULL) AND 
(pb2.custom_string_1 = 'used by macro')
order by item_code`
'''
```

Comment: [Minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem please.

Comment: Please, check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *The recursive CTE definition must contain at least two CTE query definitions, an anchor member and a recursive member. ... Anchor members must be combined by one of these set operators: UNION ALL, UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT. UNION ALL is the only set operator allowed between the last anchor member and first recursive member, and when combining multiple recursive members.* The reason is simple: DBMS cannot start recursion from nothing

Answer (score 2):

Your `temp_table4` CTE refers to itself in this line:

```
INNER JOIN temp_table4 AS tt4
```

This is legal, but it means that this CTE is recursive; recursive CTEs in SQL have always two parts: one that 'seeds' the table and that does not refer to the table itself, and the other that does. The result is the `UNION ALL` of that first `select` and the results obtained by recursively calling the second part until no more rows are added.

A typical example is something like this:

```
WITH t(id, value) as (
  SELECT id, value FROM some_table WHERE value = 10
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, value FROM some_table st JOIN t on st.value = t.value + 1
)
```

This will select first all ids where `value` is 10 and then it will keep selecting ids where `value` is one bigger than any record already selected. So it will first select all 11's, then all 12's and so on until it runs out of new records.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help guys, simplifying the code, did make a difference, allowing me to pinpoint the multiplying records and where I had added an incorrect inner join on temp_table4.

`INNER JOIN temp_table4 AS tt4 ON tt2.item_code = tt4.item_code`
which was referencing itself, and caused the error: Recursive common table expression 'temp_table4' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator

On removing the above lines from the temp_table4, the query ran successfully.

In regards to the multiple records, I noted that I had not added the inner join on the pb1.pbatch_code, once I added this to the temp table 2 and the main query as below it returned the correct number of records. :)

```
` INNER JOIN dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb2 ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt1.item_code
  INNER JOIN temp_table2 AS tt2 ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt2.item_code
  AND PB2.pbatch_code = tt2.pbatch_code
  INNER JOIN temp_table3 AS tt3 ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt3.item_code
  AND PB2.pbatch_code = tt3.pbatch_code `
```

this is a copy of my final code, maybe this can help someone else in the future, hope so.

`WITH temp_table1 AS ( SELECT MAX(start_inflow) AS Latest_start_time -- used in Tt2--   ,  custom_string_2 AS item_code, COUNT(custom_string_2) AS number_batches, SUM(duration) / 60 AS Delta_duration_sum FROM dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb1 WHERE (custom_string_1 = 'used by macro') GROUP BY custom_string_2 )  ---- Latest_start_time, DeltahoursLatestStart_time,Delta_duration_Sum , temp_table2 AS ( SELECT pb2.custom_string_2 AS item_code, DATEDIFF (minute, pb2.start_inflow, tt1.Latest_start_time) / 60.0 AS  [DeltaHoursLatestStart_time], tt1.Delta_duration_sum, pb2.pbatch_code FROM temp_table1 AS tt1 INNER JOIN dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb2 ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt1.item_code WHERE (custom_string_1 = 'used by macro') ) ----tt3.[Duration to delta]  , temp_table3 AS ( select pb2.custom_string_2 AS item_code, sum(tt2.DeltaHoursLatestStart_time) AS Duration_to_delta, pb2.pbatch_code FROM temp_table1 AS tt1 INNER JOIN dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb2 ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt1.item_code INNER JOIN temp_table2 AS tt2 ON tt1.item_code = tt2.item_code WHERE (custom_string_1 = 'used by macro') GROUP BY Pb2.custom_string_2, pb2.pbatch_code  ) select pb2.start_inflow, tt1.latest_start_time, tt1.item_code, tt1.number_batches, tt1.Delta_duration_sum, pb2.end_outflow, pb2.duration, pb2.pbatch_code, pb2.outflow_rate, pb2.qty, tt2.DeltaHoursLatestStart_time, (tt2.DeltaHoursLatestStart_time + tt3.Duration_to_delta) as [sumdeltahours], tt3.Duration_to_delta FROM temp_table1 AS tt1 INNER JOIN dbo.SUC_AS_PBATCH_ISK AS pb2 ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt1.item_code INNER JOIN temp_table2 AS tt2 ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt2.item_code AND PB2.pbatch_code = tt2.pbatch_code INNER JOIN temp_table3 AS tt3 ON pb2.custom_string_2 = tt3.item_code AND PB2.pbatch_code = tt3.pbatch_code WHERE (pb2.custom_string_2 IS NOT NULL) AND (pb2.custom_string_1 = 'used by macro')  order by item_code`